# User-friendly software for creating/designing Jasper Reports

Tags: reporting

My company has recently decided to make the move from Crystal to Jasper reporting services.Since we don't have any experience in working with or creating reports using jasper we are looking for an IDE/report creator that is hopefully easy to use and learn. We are all open to learning so that shouldn't be an issue.

Type of Application - 
Standalone Report Editors or Plugins to existing IDE's

Operating Systems we use currently - 
Win 7, Xp, 10 - Mostly windows systems

Budget - We are a small team of about 5-10 employees. We don't mind spending money as long as it's worth it.Under A $1000 a year in licencing if i had to put a number on it.

Features - 
Should be compatible with Postgres, MySql databases

Should have on-going support and/or training tools

Hopefully not an alpha-release of something as we don't want to dive headfirst into bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jasper Studio for that: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio, if that's not friendly enough, you can also try the old iReports Designer: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer, just be aware that the iReports Designer has been deprecated and it may not support the latest features.